# How to override after declaration in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I want to override some attribute in `:after` declaration in css.

```
.common-css{
     /*Some common css declation*/
}
```

Above css class have same content as in following box1 and box2 class. I don't know how to use the .common-css class in box1 and box2. and how to override the attribute `right` accoriding to css class.

Please tell me how to use class `.common-css` instead of declaration in `:after` selector and override some attribute like `right: px;`..

Please tell me how to do this effectively..

Please

```
#box1:after{

    /*Some common css declation*/
    right: 24px;

  }


#box2:after{

    /*Some css declation*/
    right: 30px;

  }
```

Comment: Give extra `common-css` class to the element.

Comment: @αƞjiβ this would not affect the `after` pseudo elements.

Comment: @lupz, plz tell me how to use class instead of declaration in `:after` selector

Comment: @geeks `<element class="common-css-class special-css-class">Element content</element>`?